# epoll file descriptor operations

Tags: c, linux, file-io, linux-kernel, epoll

I'm trying to wrap my head around epoll in Linux.
The normal operation seems to be:

```
// Create the epoll_fd
int epoll_fd = epoll_create(10);

...

// Add file descriptors to it
struct epoll_event ev = {0};
ev.events |= EPOLLIN;
ev.data.ptr = ...;

/* for brevity, I don't do error checking here */
epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, some_fd, &ev);

...

// Wait for IO events
struct epoll_event events[10];
int num_events = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, events, 10, -1);

// Now handle the events
...
```

My question is this: given the `epoll_fd` seems to be a regular file descriptor, are there any other file operations that I can do with it, besides the three epoll function calls?

Comment: Before you use `epoll` you should really ask yourself *why* you're using it. It's completely nonstandard and nonportable and does not have any measurable benefits in the vast majority of the places people use it. Unless you've increased the open file limit from 1024 to something like 50000 or more, all you're doing it making your code non-portable for no reason.

Answer (score 4):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll):

> Q3     Is the epoll fd itself
>   poll/epoll/selectable?
>
> A3     Yes.

Comment: Yes, but what does that do? What does, say, read select()-ing over that file descriptor do? What happens if I read from it?

Comment: More or less the same thing that happens when you epoll_wait, except you can do it over multiple epoll fds at once. But you probably only want one epoll FD per thread anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can `poll(2)` your `epoll_fd` itself :)